# UserTransaction used by remote clients in WildFly

Tags: jboss, wildfly-8

Is it possible to lookup and use UserTransaction from a remote-client as 
in AS 4?

I followed this document and connected from outside the server: Remote EJB invocations via JNDI - EJB client API or remote-naming project - WildFly 8 - Project Documentation Editor.

Here is the code that I used in AS 4, which failed in WildFly

Eg:

```
public void beginTransaction() {
    try {
        ut = (UserTransaction) getCtx().lookup("UserTransaction");
        ut.begin();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to begin UserTransactiion", ex);
    }
}
```

Then I got this error:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: UserTransaction -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.UserTransaction
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you now have an solution on this? I am looking for it

Comment: I started the wildfly server with the option -Djboss.node.name=node1 to make the EJBClient.getUserTransaction() method happy.
UserTransaction ut = EJBClient.getUserTransaction("node1"); This worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's now deprecated. Better use:

```
UserTransaction ut = RemoteTransactionContext.getInstance().getUserTransaction();
```

Comment: Which version of WildFly supports this?

Comment: WildFly 11 and over